# Querying mongo collection by boolean field

Tags: mongodb

I have a boolean field in a collection and I want to query all records which this field value is false.
What is the best design (performance) for this query?
Should this field save boolean true/false? true/null(exists=false)? Or maybe it has better performance for String type.. saving String/Empty String or String/null(exists=false)?
Which index should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If it's true/false it's better to store it as a boolean type. JSON supports boolean type. using it as a String "true"/"false" is not recommended as it can as a string can have "TRUE"/"FALSE" or "True"/"False", all of them adding burden in your query. There is a risk of having dirty data in that field, since it's a String.

if you check by null in a query `{'field':null}`, it includes where field doesn't exists or field value is actually null. Otherwise if you just want to get where the field is not there then use $exists `{'field' : {$exists : false}}`. Needless to say that `{'field':true}` is **NOT** same as `{'field' : {$exists : true}}`

In case you want to consider non existing field as false and want to include that logic, maybe it's better to check with $ne-  `{'field' : {$ne : true}}` . However MongoDB recommends $or rather than negative queries so something like `{$or : [{'field':null},{'field':false}]}`

All these things can be done by keeping it as a string also, but then there would be extra burden, specially if you are running a script to make a string comparison which is less reliable than boolean comparison.

Coming back to index, index doesn't work so well with boolean type, because there is not much to segregate data, but even if it's String it won't add any bite since ultimately it will have to index based on only two (or three) values. So I don't see any comparative edge.